# how can I sort items in BaseAdapter before I setAdapter?

Tags: android

I have a baseAdapter class that adds data to a Gridview.
Please is there a way to sort the list before it is added to the Adapter?

```
Comm_AppsList=new ArrayList<Appis_Infos>();
    Comm_AppsList.add(new Appis_Infos(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(com_res, R.drawable.skype), "Skype","com.skype.raider"));
    Comm_AppsList.add(new Appis_Infos(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(com_res, R.drawable.yahoomessenger),"Messenger","com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.im"));
    Comm_AppsList.add(new Appis_Infos(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(com_res, R.drawable.whatsappm),"WhatsApp","com.whatsapp"));
    Comm_AppsList.add(new Appis_Infos(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(com_res, R.drawable.yahoomail),"Mail","com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.mail"));

  Com_gridview.setAdapter(new CommAppis_Adapter(this, Comm_AppsList));
```

And here is the BaseAdapter

```
   class CommAppis_Adapter extends BaseAdapter{
private Context AIcontext;
private List<Appis_Infos>AdList;

CommAppis_Adapter(Context Aicontext, List<Appis_Infos> aDlist){
AIcontext=Aicontext;
AdList=aDlist;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return AdList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int it_position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return AdList.get(it_position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int id_position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return id_position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int Vposition, View Aview, ViewGroup Vparent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Appis_Infos appsData=AdList.get(Vposition);
    Comm_Viewholder holder=null;

    if(Aview==null){
        LayoutInflater apps_inflater=LayoutInflater.from(AIcontext);
        Aview=apps_inflater.inflate(R.layout.comm_appis, null);
        holder=new Comm_Viewholder();

        holder.apps_icons=(ImageView)Aview.findViewById(R.id.comm_imageview);
        holder.apps_name=(TextView)Aview.findViewById(R.id.comm_tvName);


        Aview.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder=(Comm_Viewholder)Aview.getTag();
    }

    holder.apps_icons.setImageBitmap(appsData.getIcon());
    holder.apps_name.setText(appsData.getName());

    return Aview;
}

}
```

Please how do I sort (Programmatically because my List is very long.I just croped it) these items before I add them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First of all you can define your own Comparator object:

```
Comparator<Appis_Infos> myComparator = new Comparator<Appis_Infos>() {
    public int compare(Appis_Infos obj1,Appis_Infos obj2) {
        return obj1.getName().compareTo(obj2.getName());
    }
 };
```

and then call the Collections.sort method:

```
Collections.sort(Comm_AppsList, myComparator);
```

If you need to compare in case invariant mode use the *compareToIgnoreCase* method instead of *compareTo*.

Comment: @ rciovati Thanks just figured it out from you answer. I appreciate. In addition I am thinking of building an android application as my Final thesis. Please do you have any idea what I can do that can be presentable? Or do you have any resources links that I can visit?

Comment: Thanks for saving my time